# calendar php data from mysql

Tags: php, logic

[image: This is table of attendance]

if want to show the attendance on student profile page. with the help of calendar. if student is present on the date the date shows in green, else in red.

Comment: Have you tried to code it?
foreach, if student is present, the date shows in green, else in red.

Comment: You are expected to write your own code. Even if it doesn't work, posting what you have tried so far allows us to better help you, and in turn, you'll learn something ;-)

Comment: i am not expert in this. can u do this ?

Comment: @Qirel i have made a calander. but i dnt know how to show data now from mysql. when i use this, loops makes the mess on the page

Comment: No, we don't make code for you.

Comment: Nobody is going to do your homework for you - you are expected to at least try something yourself. Like I said, post what you have got so far - even if it doesn't work. If you don't know where to start, [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) is a good place to start.

Comment: post some codes atleast what you have tried

Comment: @Error404 check the code i have posted.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code, try it

```
 <table id="user_cal_table" width="100%"  style=" table-layout: fixed;">
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="min-width:20%;"><strong>Sun</strong></th>
                                    <th style="min-width:20%;"><strong>Mon</strong></th>
                                    <th style="min-width:20%;"><strong>Tue</strong></th>
                                    <th style="min-width:20%;"><strong>Wed</strong></th>
                                    <th style="min-width:20%;"><strong>Thu</strong></th>
                                    <th style="min-width:20%;"><strong>Fri</strong></th>
                                    <th style="min-width:20%;"><strong>Sat</strong></th>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                                    $today = getdate();
                                    $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $cMonth, 1, $cYear);
                                    $maxday = date("t", $timestamp);
                                    $thismonth = getdate($timestamp);
                                    $startday = $thismonth['wday'];
                                    for ($i = 0; $i < ($maxday + $startday); $i++)  
                                    {
                                        if (($i % 7) == 0) 
                                            echo "<tr height='50px'>";
                                                if ($i < $startday) {
                                                    echo "<td class='invalid'></td>";
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    $thisdate = ($i - $startday + 1)."-".$thismonth['mon']."-".$thismonth['year'];
                                                    $thisdate = strtotime($thisdate);
                                                    if($thisdate<=time()) {
                                                        if(isset($attendance[$thisdate]) && $attendance[$thisdate]=="Present")
                                                            { 
                                                                echo "<td class='Present'>"; 
                                                            }
                                                        else 
                                                            {
                                                                echo "<td class='absent'>"; 
                                                            }

                                                        ?>
                                    <b><span style="padding-left:2px"><?php echo $i - $startday + 1; ?></span></b>
                                    </div></td>
                                    <?php } else { ?>
                                    <td class="otherdate"><span style="padding-left:2px"><b>{$i - $startday + 1}</b></span> </td>
                                      <?php
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if (($i % 7) == 6) {
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    for (; (($i % 7) != 0); $i++) {
                                        echo "<td class='invalid'></td>";
                                    }
                                ?>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php 
if (isset($_GET['ym'])) {
        $ym = $_GET['ym'];
    }else{
        $ym = date('Y-m');
    }
    $timestamp = strtotime($ym,"-01");
    if ($timestamp === false) {
        $timestamp = time();
    }
    // today
    $today = date('Y-m-d', time());
    // h3 title
    $html_title = date('Y / F',$timestamp);

    $prev = date('Y-m', mktime(0,0,0,date('m', $timestamp)-1,1, date('Y', $timestamp)));
    $next = date('Y-m', mktime(0,0,0,date('m', $timestamp)+1,1, date('Y', $timestamp)));

    // days numbers
    $day_count = date('t', $timestamp);
    $str = date('w', mktime(0,0,0,date('m', $timestamp),1, date('Y', $timestamp)));
    // creating calander
    $weeks = array();
    $week = '';

    $week .= str_repeat('<td style="background-color: gray"></td>', $str);
    for ($day=1; $day <= $day_count ; $day++, $str++) { 
        $date = $ym.'-'.$day;
        if ($today == $date) {
            $week .= '<td class="today" style="vertical-align: middle;"><span>'.$day.'</span>';
        }else{
            $week .= '<td style="vertical-align: middle;">'.$day;
        }
        $week .= '</td>';

        if ($str % 7 == 6 || $day == $day_count) {
            if ($day == $day_count) {
                $week .= str_repeat('<td style="background-color:gray"></td>',6 -($str % 7));
            }
            $weeks[] = '<tr>'.$week.'</tr>';

            $week = '';
        }
    }
foreach ($weeks as $week) {
                    echo $week; 
                }
         ?>
this is the calander i have made. now how to check student is present or not
```